# В игре после просмотра рекламы с вознаграждением и закрытия рекламы происходит краш. Unity Android

Tags: android, unity3d, admob

В игре после просмотра рекламы с вознаграждением и закрытия рекламы происходит краш. На айфоне такого нет, всё работает прекрасно там, но на андроид крашит игру.

Вот скрипт менеджера рекламы

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System.Collections;
using GGMatch3;

public class AdsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Variables
    private int _rewardPochta = 0;
    private int _nowRewardNumber = -1;
    private int _rewardedAdID = -1;
    private WinScreen _winScreen;
    private BonusMenu _bonusMenu;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _bonusBoosterGameScreen;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _textsMenuWaitForLoadAd;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _textsMenu;
    [SerializeField] private bool _timerStarted = false;
    [SerializeField] private GameScreen _gameScreen;
    [SerializeField] private OutOfMovesDialog _outOfMovesDialog;
    [SerializeField] private PreGameDialog _preGameDialog;
    [SerializeField] private CurrencyPanel _currencyPanel;
    [SerializeField] private BonusItem _bonusItem;
    [SerializeField] private BonusItem _bonusItemPrefab;
    [SerializeField] private Sprite[] _spritesBonusItem;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _canvas;
    private int coinsX2;

    #region Ad Keys
    [Header("AdMob Keys")]
    [SerializeField] internal string _bannerAdKey = "";
    [SerializeField] internal string _interstitialAdKey = "";
    [SerializeField] internal string _rewardedAdKey = "";
    #endregion

    #region Ad
    private InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;
    private RewardedAd _rewardedAd;
    #endregion
    #endregion

    #region Unity Behaviour
    private void Awake() => DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

    private void Start()
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
    }
    #endregion

    #region Initialize Ad
    private void OnEnable() => InitAd();

    private void InitAd()
    {
        StartCoroutine(InitAdCycle());
        InitInterstitialAd();
        InitRewardedAd();
    }

    private IEnumerator InitAdCycle()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        if (!_rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
            StartCoroutine(RewardedAdWait());
        StartCoroutine(InitAdCycle());
    }

    private void InitInterstitialAd()
    {
        _interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(_interstitialAdKey);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        _interstitialAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
        _interstitialAd.OnAdClosed += _interstitialAd_OnAdClosed;
    }

    public virtual void _interstitialAd_OnAdClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _winScreen.OnTapCallback();
        InitInterstitialAd();
    }

    private void InitRewardedAd()
    {
        StartCoroutine(RewardedAdWait());
    }

    private IEnumerator RewardedAdWait()
    {
        _rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(_rewardedAdKey);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        _rewardedAd.LoadAd(adRequest);
        _rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

        if (!_timerStarted)
        {
            if (!_rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _textsMenu.Length; i++)
                {
                    _textsMenuWaitForLoadAd[i].SetActive(true);
                    _textsMenu[i].SetActive(false);
                }
                _bonusBoosterGameScreen.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _textsMenu.Length; i++)
                {
                    _textsMenuWaitForLoadAd[i].SetActive(false);
                    _textsMenu[i].SetActive(true);
                }
                _bonusBoosterGameScreen.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

        if (!_timerStarted)
        {
            if (!_rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _textsMenu.Length; i++)
                {
                    _textsMenuWaitForLoadAd[i].SetActive(true);
                    _textsMenu[i].SetActive(false);
                }
                _bonusBoosterGameScreen.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _textsMenu.Length; i++)
                {
                    _textsMenuWaitForLoadAd[i].SetActive(false);
                    _textsMenu[i].SetActive(true);
                }
                _bonusBoosterGameScreen.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Show Ad
    public void ShowInterstitialAd(WinScreen winScreen)
    {
        _winScreen = winScreen;
        if (_interstitialAd.IsLoaded())
            _interstitialAd.Show();
        else
            winScreen.OnTapCallback();
    }

    public void ShowRewardedAdX2(WinScreen winScreen, int rewardedAdID)
    {
        if (_timerStarted) return;

        _rewardedAdID = rewardedAdID;
        _winScreen = winScreen;
        if (_rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
        {
            coinsX2 = Parser.IntParsing(_winScreen.coins.coinsLabel.text);
            _rewardedAd.Show();
        } 
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _textsMenu.Length; i++)
            {
                _textsMenuWaitForLoadAd[i].SetActive(true);
                _textsMenu[i].SetActive(false);
                _bonusBoosterGameScreen.SetActive(false);
            }
            ShowInterstitialAd(winScreen);
        } 
    }

    public void ShowRewardedAdBonus(int rewardedAdID)
    {
        if (_timerStarted) return;

        _rewardedAdID = rewardedAdID;

        if (_rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
            _rewardedAd.Show();
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _textsMenu.Length; i++)
            {
                _textsMenuWaitForLoadAd[i].SetActive(true);
                _textsMenu[i].SetActive(false);
                _bonusBoosterGameScreen.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ShowRewardedAdBonusMenu(int rewardedAdID, int nowRewardNumber, BonusMenu bonusMenu)
    {
        if (_timerStarted) return;

        _bonusMenu = bonusMenu;
        _nowRewardNumber = nowRewardNumber;
        _rewardedAdID = rewardedAdID;

        if (_rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
            _rewardedAd.Show();
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _textsMenu.Length; i++)
            {
                _textsMenuWaitForLoadAd[i].SetActive(true);
                _textsMenu[i].SetActive(false);
                _bonusBoosterGameScreen.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ShowRewardedAdPochtaMenu(int rewardedAdID, int rewardPochta)
    {
        if (_timerStarted) return;

        _rewardPochta = rewardPochta;
        _rewardedAdID = rewardedAdID;

        if (_rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
            _rewardedAd.Show();
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _textsMenu.Length; i++)
            {
                _textsMenuWaitForLoadAd[i].SetActive(true);
                _textsMenu[i].SetActive(false);
                _bonusBoosterGameScreen.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleUserEarnedReward(object sender, Reward e)
    {
        if (_rewardedAdID == 0)
            _winScreen.OnTapCallback();
        WalletManager walletManager = GGPlayerSettings.instance.walletManager;
        switch (_rewardedAdID)
        {
            case 0:
                walletManager.AddCurrency(CurrencyType.coins, coinsX2);
                StartCoroutine(LabelsReset());
                break;
            case 1:
                PlayerInventory.instance.Add(BoosterType.BombBooster, 1);
                _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[3], 1);
                _preGameDialog.PreGameDialogBoosterPrefabs[0].ButtonCallback_OnClick();
                break;
            case 2:
                BuyMovesPricesConfig.OfferConfig offer2 = ScriptableObjectSingleton<BuyMovesPricesConfig>.instance.GetOfferNew(5);
                Match3Game game2 = _outOfMovesDialog.game;
                walletManager.BuyItem(offer2.price);
                game2.ContinueGameAfterOffer(offer2);
                _gameScreen.goalsPanel.UpdateMovesCount();
                _outOfMovesDialog.Hide();
                Analytics.MovesBoughtEvent movesBoughtEvent2 = new Analytics.MovesBoughtEvent();
                movesBoughtEvent2.stageState = _gameScreen.stageState;
                movesBoughtEvent2.offer = offer2;
                movesBoughtEvent2.Send();
                break;
            case 3:
                int rand = Random.Range(6, 8);
                Debug.LogError(rand);
                BuyMovesPricesConfig.OfferConfig offer3 = ScriptableObjectSingleton<BuyMovesPricesConfig>.instance.GetOfferNew(rand);
                walletManager.BuyItem(offer3.price);
                FindObjectOfType<Match3Game>().ContinueGameAfterOffer(offer3);
                _gameScreen.goalsPanel.UpdateMovesCount();
                //_outOfMovesDialog.Hide();
                /*Analytics.MovesBoughtEvent movesBoughtEvent3 = new Analytics.MovesBoughtEvent();
                movesBoughtEvent3.stageState = _gameScreen.stageState;
                movesBoughtEvent3.offer = offer3;
                movesBoughtEvent3.Send();*/
                break;
            case 4:
                switch (_nowRewardNumber)
                {
                    case 1:
                        walletManager.AddCurrency(CurrencyType.coins, 50);
                        _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                        _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[0], 50);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        PlayerInventory.instance.Add(PowerupType.PowerHammer, 1);
                        _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                        _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[1], 1);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        walletManager.AddCurrency(CurrencyType.coins, 60);
                        _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                        _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[0], 60);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        PlayerInventory.instance.Add(BoosterType.VerticalRocketBooster, 1);
                        _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                        _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[2], 1);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        walletManager.AddCurrency(CurrencyType.coins, 70);
                        _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                        _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[0], 70);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        PlayerInventory.instance.Add(BoosterType.BombBooster, 1);
                        _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                        _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[3], 1);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        walletManager.AddCurrency(CurrencyType.coins, 80);
                        _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                        _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[0], 80);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        PlayerInventory.instance.Add(BoosterType.DiscoBooster, 1);
                        _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                        _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[4], 1);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        walletManager.AddCurrency(CurrencyType.coins, 90);
                        _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                        _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[0], 90);
                        break;
                }
                StartCoroutine(LabelsReset());
                _bonusMenu.NowRewardNumberSet(_nowRewardNumber+1);
                break;
            case 5:
                switch (_rewardPochta)
                {
                    case 1:
                        walletManager.AddCurrency(CurrencyType.coins, 100);
                        _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                        _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[0], 100);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        BehaviourSingleton<EnergyManager>.instance.FillEnergy();
                        _bonusItem = Instantiate(_bonusItemPrefab, _canvas);
                        _bonusItem.SetImageSprite(_spritesBonusItem[5], 5);
                        break;
                }
                StartCoroutine(LabelsReset());
                break;
        }
        StartCoroutine(TimerToNextRewardedAd());
        StartCoroutine(RewardedAdWait());
    }

    private IEnumerator LabelsReset()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        _currencyPanel.SetLabels();
    }

    private IEnumerator TimerToNextRewardedAd()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _textsMenu.Length; i++)
        {
            _textsMenuWaitForLoadAd[i].SetActive(true);
            _textsMenu[i].SetActive(false);
        }
        _bonusBoosterGameScreen.SetActive(false);
        _timerStarted = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(20f);
        _timerStarted = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < _textsMenu.Length; i++)
        {
            _textsMenuWaitForLoadAd[i].SetActive(false);
            _textsMenu[i].SetActive(true);
            _bonusBoosterGameScreen.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Вот логи ошибки (не уверен, что вычерпнул именно те логи)

```
2022-04-15 01:17:06.948 8716-8716/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.online.homedesign, PID: 8716
    java.lang.Error: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Version '2021.1.1f1 (6fdc41dfa55a)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a12snsser/a12s:11/RP1A.200720.012/A127FXXU4AVB3:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '1'
    ABI: 'arm64'
    Timestamp: 2022-04-15 00:17:04+1000
    pid: 8716, tid: 11290, name: Thread-137  >>> com.online.homedesign <<<
    uid: 10391
    signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
    Cause: null pointer dereference
        x0  00000079d0261810  x1  0000000000000000  x2  00000078c0e96fc0  x3  0000000000000000
        x4  0000000000000001  x5  0000007a40dbb885  x6  00000078c0e96fe0  x7  00000078c0e96f80
        x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000000  x11 0000000000000000
        x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000000000000000  x14 0000000000000000  x15 0000000000000000
        x16 0000007a410e2af8  x17 0000007b37542f7c  x18 00000078ac42e000  x19 0000007970107af0
        x20 0000000000000000  x21 0000000000000001  x22 00000078c0e9a000  x23 0000000000000000
        x24 0000000000000001  x25 0000007970107ce0  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000000000000080
        x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000000000000000
        sp  00000078c0e96f20  lr  0000007a4077e724  pc  0000007a4077e724
    
    backtrace:
          #00 pc 00000000006b9724  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #01 pc 00000000006bb23c  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #02 pc 00000000006bb420  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #03 pc 00000000003c018c  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #04 pc 0000000001355de0  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #05 pc 000000000071bad4  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #06 pc 000000000071ba34  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #07 pc 00000000003191c0  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #08 pc 0000000000326b74  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #09 pc 0000000000328908  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #10 pc 000000000036607c  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #11 pc 0000000000333814  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #12 pc 0000000000333bec  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #13 pc 000000000033377c  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
2022-04-15 01:17:06.948 8716-8716/? E/AndroidRuntime:       #14 pc 0000000000367448  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #15 pc 0000000000367324  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #16 pc 00000000001f9450  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #17 pc 00000000001f9aec  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #18 pc 00000000003c9d50  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #19 pc 00000000011772d8  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #20 pc 0000000000c67a30  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #21 pc 00000000019755a4  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #22 pc 00000000014383a0  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #23 pc 00000000014383a0  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #24 pc 000000000071bad4  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #25 pc 000000000071ba34  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #26 pc 00000000007203e0  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #27 pc 00000000006f6fa4  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #28 pc 00000000011f8384  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #29 pc 00000000018feef8  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #30 pc 0000000001901e38  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #31 pc 000000000060a458  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #32 pc 000000000071bb44  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #33 pc 000000000071ba34  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: 23fa362d7205e108f9a31aca3ac35a2ee48207e9)
          #34 pc 00000000003191c0  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
2022-04-15 01:17:06.948 8716-8716/? E/AndroidRuntime:       #35 pc 0000000000326b74  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #36 pc 00000000001a2900  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: e6970e0e313d9864ab99213980a6f90c2bd9751a)
          #37 pc 0000000000035aa0  /data/app/~~tTlS3KtHXVObcco3J7JQpg==/com.online.homedesign-3erG8YIXM1bF1BwEZnU-yA==/oat/arm64/base.odex
    
        at libunity.0x6b9724(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x6bb23c(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x6bb420(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x3c018c(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x1355de0(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x71bad4(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x71ba34(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x3191c0(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x326b74(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x328908(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x36607c(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x333814(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x333bec(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x33377c(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x367448(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x367324(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x1f9450(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x1f9aec(Native Method)
        at libunity.0x3c9d50(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x11772d8(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0xc67a30(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x19755a4(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x14383a0(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x14383a0(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x71bad4(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x71ba34(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x7203e0(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x6f6fa4(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x11f8384(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x18feef8(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x1901e38(Native Method)
        at libil2cpp.0x60a458(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не использовать Instantiate в методе получения вознаграждения после окончания просмотра рекламы.